# Connected sum $S_1$ # $S_2$ is commutative and associative

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, associativity, classifying-spaces

The connected sum of two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ is formed by removing a circular hole from each surface and identifying the boundaries together

> Show that the connected sum $S_1$ # $S_2$ is commutative and associative

It seems reasonable that, up to homeomorphism:

- $S_1$ # $S_2=S_2$ # $S_1$
- ($S_1$ # $S_2$)#$S_3$ = $S_1$ # ($S_2$#$S_3$)

How could I show this explicitly?

Comment: this is a bit of a weird question to bother with, but you should write down the connect sum explicitly as a quotient of the disjoint union, and use associativity and commutativity of disjoint union and quotients.